# How to create an array as such using javascript

Tags: javascript

Using javascript, I want to create an array that has the structure so that it can have all states within the country array. Each state would be an array consisting all the regions within it. And each region would contain all the health clubs within it. Something like this:

```
[Australia]=>array([NSW]=>array([Sydney]=>array(element1, element2, ...)));
```

So far I have tried many things including the code below:

```
$('#search-widget-data li').each(function(){
var dataElement = $(this);
searchWidgetData.push(dataElement.text());
alldata.push([dataElement.prevAll(".state:first").text(),             
dataElement.prevAll(".region:first").text());
});
```

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: I have a big list of things from where I get raw list of elements, I have tried to push things by fetching for the previous state/regions/clubs in the list

Answer (score 2):

You can use a form like this:

```
var countries = [
    {
        name: "Australia",
        states: [
            {
                name: "state1",
                regions: [
                    {
                        name: "region1",
                        healthclubs: [
                            "healthclub1", "healthclub2"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: "region2",
                        healthclubs: [
                            "healthclub1", "healthclub2"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "state2",
                regions: [
                    {
                        name: "region1",
                        healthclubs: [
                            "healthclub1", "healthclub2"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "USA"
    }
];
```

You may want to store your data structure in the [JSON](http://json.org/example.html) format which will make it easy for storage and working with as a JavaScript object.

Answer (score -1):

You may try this one out.


var regArr[n1][n2];


but you need to specify the length of each inner array.